# Troubleshooting fried FPV receiver hooked up to SPDT switch

Tags: switches, receiver

I want to be able to charge a FPV Receiver [(specs)](https://www.banggood.com/Eachine-ROTG01-Pro-UVC-OTG-5_8G-150CH-Full-Channel-FPV-Receiver-WAudio-For-Android-Smartphone-p-1347396.html?rmmds=search&ID=224&cur_warehouse=CN) via a phone and charge the phone with a battery. I tried using a single pole double throw switch without the power source connected to the phone first. So essentially it was a ON/OFF switch for the receiver to receive 5V from the phone. This worked the first time, but when I tried it again the receiver didn't work. I can't imagine how my setup is different from connecting and disconnecting the micro-usb to the receiver (its intended use). I took care not to short any of the wires.

Here is my wiring. The power wire from the phone (red) goes to the middle terminal and the power  wire for the device goes to the right terminal from respective micro usbs. Everything else is connected (data + , data -, ground). Is there anything wrong that could have screwed up the receiver ? 
[image: enter image sdfasdfasdfdescription here]

The receiver is connected to phone. I eventually want to add a power source for the phone to the switch.

[image]

The schematic below includes the power source, which I did not connect to the switch for my failed test.

[image: schematic]

Comment: the top picture is not very clear but it appears to show sloppy soldering

Comment: There are enough stray copper threads in that photo to explain anything blowing up. So. yes.